# Making a div editable via jquery works in all browsers except IE7+

Tags: jquery

I'm using the editable jquery plugin (http://www.tectual.com.au/posts/7/jQuery-Editable-Plugin-Best-In-Place-Editor-.html)

When using the following code to make a div editable, it only seems to work in all browsers except IE.

Interestingly, on the author's plugin site, I have tested it in IE, and the plugin seems to work fine, so i'm wondering if it's something specific to what I'm doing?

Here's the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.edit').editable('', {
     indicator : 'Saving...',
     onblur : 'submit',
     style   : 'display: inline'
 });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`div` can be set to be editable without using any js. set `contentEditable = "true"` and you are done.

```
<div style="width:200px;height:300px;border:2px solid red;" contentEditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, but i need it to empty the text in the div upon click and to save the text upon pressing enter, is that possible using this method?

Comment: I dont want them to be able to enter more than one line of text basically.

Comment: If more than one line is not needed then why dont you make a simple input type = text

Comment: I have. This is what I've got but it still seems to allow multiple lines of text.

h1 class="storytitle" id="storytitle" align="center" input type = "text" contentEditable="true">

Comment: you cannot set contentEditable property for text type. It is always editable